# RadioButton circle spacing

Tags: java, android

I have a radio button with a selector background and an animation.
All of them work correctly. But there is a problem with the alignment of the circle in the radio button. When I try to set the margin to it, It changes with the background drawable. Is there any way to move the radio button's circle only?

Also please help me in the case of checkboxes.

```
rbtn_selector.xml

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_checked="true">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#8effffff" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_checked="false">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#51ffffff" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

```
activity_radio.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/back1"
tools:context="com.wiinnova.custom_views.RadioActivity">

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rbtn_selector"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="apple"/>

</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: share your code.

Comment: post your code plz

Comment: use custom images in the checkbox and radio button , and give the padding in the canvas of the image and making the canvas tranparent. padding should be equal. your designer will understand.

Comment: Ok, I understand that, Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used a custom image for the radio button drawable with some transparent padding. And replaced that selected drawable at the same position as for click effects. And created a selector to change the drawable while checking the radio button.

Thanks Mohit

Answer (score 0):

Try by setting background `android:background="@drawable/rbtn_selector"` to `RadioGroup` instead of `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/back1"
tools:context="com.wiinnova.custom_views.RadioActivity">

<RadioGroup
android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="@drawable/rbtn_selector"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="apple"/>

</RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But that was not my problem, I have to move the circle of the radio button